# Python Selenium unable to find text of iterative span classes

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Unable to get the "span text" printed.

**Expected Output**

```
Hello-World
Foo-Bar
```

**Given HTML Snippet:**

```
<div class="information-container">
  <ul>
          <li class="info-item">
              <span class="info-text">
                     Hello-World

              </span>
          </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
          <li class="info-item">
              <span class="info-text">

                      Foo-Bar

              </span>
          </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**My parse Code (Method 1):**

```
page = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("information-container")
for elem in page.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "info-text"]'):
            print("E>", elem.text)
            attrs = self.browser.execute_script('var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;', elem)
            pprint(attrs)
```

***Output (Method 1):***

```
E>
{'class': 'info-text'}
E>
{'class': 'info-text'}
```

**My parse Code (Method 2):**

```
page = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("information-container")
li_objs = page.find_elements_by_class_name('info-text')
for o in li_objs:
    print("text:", o.text)
```

***Output (Method 2):***

```
text:
text:
```

Comment: I have tried both your methods and they work as intended at my end. The only difference is that I am running under a direct instance of webdriver, not as part of a class method i.e. `browser.find_elements...` not `self.browser...`. My guess is the issue lies with the way you defined your class method and/or the call to the instance method, which you haven't shared in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The text from all span tags on a page can be displayed using the following

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'path_to_driver')
driver.get('path_to_site')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')

for element in elements:
    text = element.text
    print(text)
```